# Build webRTC for android on windows

Tags: android, webrtc

I am working with [webRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android). I want to build it for android to do peer to peer streaming. I think i can do that using that webRTC-android-app, right? So my question how can i build it on windows because if you go to the link the first line says "Android development is only supported on Linux."

So it's possible to build that on windows or i have to switch to Linux for that project?

Comment: You can develop it in Windows. In the link you provide, under "Prerequsite software", you can find what you need to install in your windows machine. Good luck.

Comment: BTW this android webrtc-android-app do a peer to peer stream between two android devices on local network?

Comment: did you build it on android. it's been a whole day i am not able to build it. Can you help me here

Comment: Hi! What errors do you get?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to try use Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/). Please be sure that you are using x64 version. I would also recommend you to setup "devel" package during installation process. apt-cyg (https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/) will be also helpful for you.

The build steps will be similar with build steps for Linux, but all operations will be done under cygwin console.

The main advantage of this way is that you can easily integrate Cygwin bash with your IDE on windows (e.g. eclipse) and build WebRTC library as a part of your project build process.

Comment: I think you have to look into [Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC)